# Calling a function in the class that extend current abstract class

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

I have an `Connection` class which connects to a specific "`Service`". You call the specific `Service` such as `mysqli` or `PDO` when instantiating the class.

```
class Connection
{

    private $service;

    private $state = null;

    public function __construct(Service $service) {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    public function initialize() {
       ....
    }

    public function destruct() {
       ....
    }

    //Maybe some getters and setters
}
```

In the `Service` class there is an `getObject()` method, this contains the object which has to be instantiated to make a connection to a Database or something else.

There is also an `getInstance()` method. This is used for returning the object in the `getObject` method if it isnt already instantiated.

```
abstract class Service
{

    public static function getInstance() {
        $instance = null;
        if ($instance == null) {
            $instance = self::getObject();
        }
        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * @return object Returns the object where the service should start from.
     */
    public abstract function getObject();
}
```

Here is an example of an Service class.

```
class MySQLService extends Service
{

    public function getObject() {
        return new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'db');
    }
}
```

**Problem**

When using this code like this:

```
$connection = new Connection(MySQLService::getInstance());
$connection->initialize();
```

It comes with this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot call abstract method Service::getObject() in
>   C:\Users.\Documents...\Service.php on line 18

**Questions**

- How does it come that this error appears?
- How can I solve this error?
- How can I call a function from a class that extends the `Service` class?

Comment: I think your problem is with the `self::getObject()`. You don't want the `getObject()` from `Service Class` but from `MySQLService Class`.

Comment: @RST Indeed, or other classes extended by the `Service` class

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this working you need to declare the `getObject` methods as the static methods they are.

In `Service`:

```
public abstract function getObject()
```

Should be:

```
public static function getObject() {}
```

(Sorry, you can't have a static abstract)

In `MySQLService`:

```
public function getObject() {
```

Should be:

```
public static function getObject() {
```

You can then direct the call to the right class by using the following:

```
public static function getInstance() {
    static $instance = null;
    if ($instance == null) {
        $instance = static::getObject();
    }
    return $instance;
```

}

Note - you missed the `static` keyword from the instance variable too.

Comment: Alright then, thanks :) But how can I then force the classes to have an `getObject()` method? And why do i have to make the `$instance` variable static? And what does the `static::` word do?

Comment: Yep - tricky!  Alas, if you want to call it statically you can't make it abstract (as far as I am aware). Someone else may well come along and tell me I'm wrong!

Comment: My IDE (PhpStorm) is giving an error about it too, it says: PHP Strict Standards: Static function getObject() should not be abstract

Comment: Yes - you can't have a static abstract function - that's what I'm saying... You can't declare `public abstract static function getObject()` - it should be `public static function getObject() {}`

Comment: Yeah, but is'nt there any way to force the class to have that `getObject` method?